# R error handling when calling another R script

Tags: r, error-handling, try-catch

So I have an R script (`Master.R`) which calls another R script (`minor.R`) and I want to be alerted to when the `minor.R` errors out.

I tried to follow the suggestion in [R Script - How to Continue Code Execution on Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8852406/r-script-how-to-continue-code-execution-on-error), but it isnt returning anything when the script errors.

R script master:

```
# run minor.R
res1 = try({system(paste("Rscript minor.R", var1))})
if(inherits(res1, "try-error")){
         print("Hey, a warning")
}
```

I also tried

```
tryCatch({system(paste("Rscript minor.R", var1))},
         error = function(e) {print("Hey, a warning")})
```

But no luck, when the code errors it does not return the phrase.

How can I catch the error and get it to execute a subsequent piece of code?

Comment: If I run `tryCatch({system(paste("Rscript minor.R", var1))},
         error = function(e) {print("Hey, a warning")})` as it is and since I don't have that script it returns me the phrase as expected.

Comment: I suspect that it because the script does not run, however what happens if the script does run but then errors out? In my case no error is returned.

Comment: I found that if I put the tryCatch statement round the whole `minor.R` script then that worked instead. I think the error is not being passed to `master.R`.